# HOW-TO creata TTS button with Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, text-to-speech

I am trying to create a simple read out-loud (TTS) button for my blog posts. 
The idea is to have a button by the title that will allow users to listen 
to the post once clicked.

MY APPROACH:
Created a Bootstrap button, imported a GoogleTTS engine. However I have no idea how to link the TTS engine and then have it read the text within the HTML page in the blog post.

Coding Help will be most appreciated, as well as alternative solutions. Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Not sure if this is feedback or just a suggestion. I searched through all the questions available and I am pretty sure there wasn't one similar or related to mine.

Comment: it means that you have not provided any code you have tried, making it hard for the community to help you with whatever issue you are having, it seems you just want people to write code for you.